# Synching files between IOS device and database

Tags: c#, ios, database, synchronization, xamarin

I'm working on an IOS-application, in which I send and receive files (text files) to and from a database. One of the requirements is that you can still "send" files when you're not connected to the internet (or cellular data).

The idea I had was, when you were to send a file while you're not connected to the internet, it would save the file locally. Then, when you send a file when you do have an internet connection, it would take all the files that were saved locally and send them all at once. Problem is, how do I discriminate between the files that I already downloaded from the database and the files that I still need to upload?

Any ideas are welcome. And if you have a better solution for this problem, I'll be glad to hear it.

With kind regards,
Björn

Comment: you can have additional bool field - uploaded against each entry in your local database defaulted to false and you'll set it to true when uploaded..

Comment: Create list of files you have(list1) and get list of files in database(list2). And just find diff `filesToUpload =  list1.Except(list2)` `filesToDownload=list2.Except(list1)`

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. It's like this: I want to distinguish the files that are stored locally into two groups. The ones that I downloaded earlier and the ones that I haven't uploaded yet. I don't need a list that tells me which files to download, since I send all the new files that are stored locally to the database, and then download all entries from the database, overriding the local files. This way, any new entries in the database that aren't mine get added to the list of files on my IOS device, and I don't have to fumble with which files to download from the database.